# Installing outlet receptacle in unfinished basement furnace/water heater room

Tags: electrical, basement, receptacle

Recently bought a house with a furnace/water heater utility room in the basement surrounded by a bedroom and playroom space. We just had a water filtration system put in this room that requires a plug. I thought it was really odd that there was no outlet receptacle in this room. My plan is to piggyback off the bedroom receptacle, but I want to make sure that there's nothing in the code about not putting receptacles X distance from water heater or furnace. I'm tracking that it's unfinished basement so the first outlet of the double duplex needs to be GFCI. Am I missing anything? Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to install the incoming power to the line side of the GFCI and the other outlet in the same box to the load side. That way both outlet's get protection from the GFCI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special needed here except the GFCI since this room is not finished. Finished rooms in a basement depending on how long back may not have AFCI or GFCI protection but adding a receptacle in an unfinished basement room would require a GFCI even if no water present.  The outlet can be directly adjacent to the equipment no spacing is required no covers or anything else is required by the national electric code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the load on the bedroom outlet to make sure it will handle the water filtering system. No problem piggybacking off that outlet. Yes, the first outlet needs to be GFIC and the second outlet needs to be GFIC protected by connecting it to the load terminals of the GFIC outlet. good luck

Comment: The bedroom doesn’t require a GFCI NEC 210.8.A.5. Unfinished portions or areas of basement not intended as habitable rooms require GFCI

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. The first outlet in the double duplex needs to be a GFCI and the second outlet can be protected from it.

Comment: I read it differently the first time and see your point after rereading, if there are 4 outlets in the new room protecting the second set from the load of the GFCI will work. I was thinking the OP was tapping a duplex bringing the tap to the new room and that was the only outlet , but the OP did say double duplex +

Answer (score -2):

If there’s any chance of moisture in the room use weatherproof receptacle boxes and UF-B plastic sheathed cable - more abrasion resistance too, so good in a utility room. You can get moisture resistant clamps for the cable that screw directly into the box.

Alternatively you could use EMT and draw separate wires and ground. Again I’d see if there are moisture resistant fittings and boxes available if the room tends to have any moisture.

Check code requirement for distances of outlets - from any permanent fixtures that dispense water, like faucets. Water heaters do have drain fittings, and piping on top.

If the filtration system has a hookup box, you can use a sheathed hookup, typically epoxy coated flexible with (2 or 3 wires & ground) larger gauge wires, such as #10. These are usually used for outdoor appliances like a/c compressors, but I think they’re a good choice for many utility appliances, and in some cases are required. They can be purchased at supply houses and possibly at bigbox stores.

Another requirement may be a remote switch or way to remove power from the appliance(s) such as a wire you can unplug or if it’s hardwired, it should be attached to a box with a builtin cutoff switch. This allows the appliance to be de-energized locally for service.

Comment: Got to - this one, there is a requirement for an outlet to be within 3’ from a basin in a bathroom and an outlet must be within 24” from a sink in a kitchen and it can be directly adjacent or even behind in the case of a large enough space. The time where there is a spacing required is when the outlet is below a sink.  Other than a bath tub / shower the areas inside a house are dry locations and nothing other than a GFCI is needed in this room because it is unfinished in a basement. Finished rooms did not require GFCI/AFCI in the past so their may not be one in the bedroom.

Comment: My comment got two long, please don’t make things up. Code scares enough DIY folks away and you have a massive amount of mis-information in your post. If you feel your correct provide code references you might want to review 210.8, 406.5 & 406.9 and brush up on what is and is not required.

Comment: I read this awhile ago, and it makes sense not to have electrical outlets inside the splash zone for sinks. I see NEC varies from this sensible req.  Any positives in the rest of what I wrote or are you only negative? Did you have any positive contributions? I did....